# Convergence Range of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \times\frac{(2n-1)^{2n} (x-1)^n}{(3n-2)^{2n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \times\frac{(2n-1)^{2n} (x-1)^n}{(3n-2)^{2n}}$$

Applying ratio test to get an $x$ that converges:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \lim_{n \to \infty} |(x-1) \frac{(2n+1)^{2n+2} (3n-2)^{2n}}{(3n+1)^{2n+2} (2n-1)^{2n}}| < 1$$

As $n \rightarrow \infty$ wouldn't the two terms go to $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{3}{2}$ and cancel each other out leading to the expression:

$$|(x-1)| < 1 \rightarrow 0< x< 2$$

The provided answer is $\frac{-5}{4} < x < \frac{13}{4}$, however I am having troubles getting to this conclusion. Perhaps a dumb mistake. Could someone point it out?

Comment: Just use the root test. You get $|x-1|<(3/2)^2$.

Comment: Ah ok. Why doesn't this work though? Is there a reason?

Comment: It has to work. Quotient test is the weaker version of the root test. You just made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

You said the two terms go to $\frac 23$ and $\frac 32$. This is not correct

As pointed by @Jacobian, the root test
gives
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}|a_n|^\frac 1n = \frac 49|x-1|$$

So, $$\frac 49|x-1|<1\iff$$
$$|x-1|<\frac 94 \iff $$
$$-\frac 94<x-1<\frac 94 \iff$$
$$-\frac 54<x<\frac{13}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

The root test is definitely the way to go on this one, but the ratio test still works fine, as long as you know the formulas for exponentials:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|(x-1) \frac{(2n+1)^{2n+2} (3n-2)^{2n}}{(3n+1)^{2n+2} (2n-1)^{2n}}\right| \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} |x-1| \left| \frac{(2n+1)^{2n+2} (3n-2)^{2n}}{(2n-1)^{2n} (3n+1)^{2n+2}}\right|\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} |x-1| \left| \frac{(2n+1)^{2n+2}}{ (2n-1)^{2n}}\right| \left|\frac{ (3n-2)^{2n}}{(3n+1)^{2n+2} }\right|\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} |x-1| \left| \frac{(2n+1)^{2n+2}}{ (2n-1)^{2n}}\right| \left|\frac{ (3n-2)^{2n}}{(3n+1)^{2n+2} }\right|\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} |x-1| \left|\frac{2n+1}{3n+1} \right|^2 \left| \frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\right|^{2n} \left|\frac{3n-2}{3n+1} \right|^{2n}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} |x-1| \left|\frac{2n+1}{3n+1} \right|^2 \left| 1 + \frac{2}{2n-1}\right|^{2n} \left|1 - \frac{3}{3n+1}\right|^{2n}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} |x-1| \left|\frac{2+1/n}{3+1/n} \right|^2 \left| 1 + \frac{1}{n-1/2}\right|^{2n} \left|1 - \frac{1}{n+1/3}\right|^{2n}\\
&= \left|x-1\right| \cdot \frac 4 9 \cdot e^2 \cdot e^{-2}\\
&=  \frac 4 9 \left|x-1\right|\\
\end{align}

and continue from there.

When doing the ratio test, it's important to combine like terms (like-enough, anyway) before making conclusions about the limit. Things are straightforward if the coefficients are rational functions in $n$, or if they are exponentials of $n$. When they are mixed like this, though, you tend to get exponential expressions.